# Add another mailbox to Outlook 2013 automatically

Tags: outlook-2010, exchange-server-2010, outlook-2013

I have a peculiar request. I manage our departments IT needs. One of the things that we do is we all share the department's mailbox. So, the way I have it setup currently is that the department's mailbox shows up as proxy on the user's mailbox, and they have editor rights to the mailbox. However, in the past few weeks, we ran into a few technical issues with the workstations, and users had to share another computer. However, when they share the other open computer, they still log in using their domain account. With that said, what I wanted to do was to let the Outlook or Exchange server decide what mailboxes they get automatically instead of just their mailbox. Currently, when they log in to the domain computer, Outlook resolves their email account, and sets up the Mailbox for them. Can we make Outlook or Exchange server add an additional mailbox when they start Outlook automatically?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you assign the users full mailbox access via esm than the shared mailbox will automatically appear as additinal mailbox in the outlook folder list, however they're own user mailbox will be the primary mailbox.
Please note that if many users open the same mailbox it might get to the maximum allowed rpc connections and users will start failing access to the shared mailbom

Comment: thanks but that's not what I'm looking for. I don't wanna make them the owner of the mailbox. There are several other folders in the mailbox that I don't want everyone to see or have ownership. Currently, they're editors of certain folders. I'm adding the department mailbox as their secondary mailbox manually. I'd like thus to be done using OCT or Group Policy.

Comment: I see I have made a mistake in my question. I've only given them the editor permission not the full rights. My apologies.